# Get data from Json response from urllib using python

Tags: python, urllib

I am getting data from an API call using the following Python code.

```
import urllib.request
import json

response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
string = response.read().decode('utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(string)
print(json_obj)
```

The result set is as below:

```
{"forecast": [645.946539419183], "index": [{"Date": 1629072000000, "ProductType": "Type1"}]}
```

How can I just return the forecast value?

```
645.946539419183
```

I have tried many things to get the value but nothing seems to be working

```
print(json_obj['forecast'][0])
```

Throws the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-af91dd9fcc96> in <module>
     37     json_obj = json.loads(string)
     38 
---> 39     print(json_obj['forecast'][0])
     40 
     41 except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: How can `json_obj` be a string when it is the return from `json.loads()`?

Comment: Looks like the error you shared does not match the code you have posted.

Comment: @balderman I have double checked and the code and error message are an exact match

Comment: Could you please show the output of `type(json_obj)` please? Your information seems incoherent with the documentation...

Comment: @BlackBeans good call, it returns this `print(type(json_obj))` return `<class 'str'>`

Comment: Are you **sure** your code contains `json.loads`, and not `json.dumps`?

Comment: @BlackBeans but I thought this line `json_obj = json.loads(string)` should convert the string into json?

Comment: So what do you get with `print(string)`?

Comment: @BlackBeans my code definitely has `json.loads()` , in the question above I have copy pasted the exact code without any change

Comment: Ah, I got it, maybe `string` starts and ends with quotes? In which case the problem probably comes from the site from which you retrieve your data, which exposes a strange API...

Comment: `print(string)` gives me this `"{\"forecast\": [645.946539419183], \"index\": [{\"SaleDate\": 1629072000000, \"ProductType\": \"Type1\"}]}"`

Comment: And then: `print(response.json()['forecast'])`?

Comment: Try out my answer, to see if that works, I have edited it.

Comment: @quamrana your suggested method returned this error "AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'json'"

Comment: is it possible to get the url you are accessing? to recreate this need the URL, otherwise @balderman answer would have been accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
json_obj = json.loads(json.loads(string))
json_obj["forecast"][0]
```

The second indexing is required because the value you seek is in a list.

This works, but I want to stress out that there is probably a bug in the service that provides the string, since it encoded twice the data...

Comment: This is also throwing an error " except urllib.error.HTTPError as error: ypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: throwing a different error this time `
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
`

Comment: @M.Ali Ok, last attempt, try this one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help mate, really appreciate you helping me with this :D the last one has worked :D

Comment: @M.Ali I don't know if you are the one coding the API from which you are retrieving the information, but it is very likely a bug that the information was encoded twice. Try patching the bug, then the previous solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
json_obj = {"forecast": [645.946539419183], "index": [{"Date": 1629072000000, "ProductType": "Type1"}]}
print(json_obj['forecast'][0])
```

The code above works.

Comment: This is also throwing an error " except urllib.error.HTTPError as error: ypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: see my comment above - the error and the code does not match! Can you share the url so we can test it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
forecast = json_obj['forecast']
```